# Get part of XML as string

Tags: php, xml

may be this question is too simple to be here but I can't find the solution.

So I have XML data, like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<PPMDResults s="CB-API02" lst="6/17/2014 12:30:27 AM">
    <Results success="1" api="1" version="7.0">
        <usercontext providerid="0">99123928537B35324243375D213E687D</usercontext>
    </Results>
</PPMDResults>
```

So I need to get (as a string) only

```
<usercontext providerid="0">99123928537B35324243375D213E687D</usercontext>
```

part from all this data.

I tried to process it with SimpleXML and so on, but no luck, I can get only node value, not the whole node as it is.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`asXML`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) on any `SimpleXML` element:

```
echo $xml->Results->asXML();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your structure is known (and simple like it is in your example) you can use RegEX:

```
/(<usercontext.*usercontext>)/
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nQ6jA5)

Comment: This is a `rm -rf` type of suggestion, easy to break.